# Sphere centered in line $(x,y,z) = (-2,0,1) + \lambda (0,0,1)$ tangent to planes $ x-10z = 0 $ and $ x+2z = 0 $ whose radius squared is $r^2 > 20$

Tags: analytic-geometry

how may I find the sphere centered in line

$$(x,y,z) = (-2,0,1) + \lambda (0,0,1)$$

tangent to planes $$ x-10z = 0 $$

and

$$ x+2z = 0 $$

whose radius squared is

$$r^2 > 20$$

Thank you.

[image: Geogebra screen capture]

[image: Intersection points]

Comment: at first i would draw a picture

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner hello Dr. Sonnhard, I just attached a screen capture from Geogebra of the problem. Can you help me figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Note that the problem can be reduced to the plane $x-z$ (i.e. $y=0$) where the section of the sphere is a circle of center $C=(-2,\lambda)$ and the sections of the two planes are the straight lines:
$$
\alpha) \quad x-10z=0 \qquad \beta) \quad x+2z=0
$$

The center have to be such that its [distances from these lines](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Point-LineDistance2-Dimensional.html) are the same:
$$
\frac{|-2-10\lambda|}{\sqrt{1^2+10^2}}=\frac{|-2+2\lambda|}{\sqrt{1^2+2^2}}
$$

can you do from this?

Comment: Yes I can Emilio, thank you very much. Best Regards.